# xctestcase run tests when a pretest is passed

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos, xctest

I have several test cases in a `XCTestCase` class e.g. test1, test2 etc. 
I want to run `test1, test2` only if `testPrecondition` is passed. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

You have to override testInvocations class method of XCtest. Following example is from [Github](https://github.com/0xced/XCDYouTubeKit/blob/master/XCDYouTubeKit%20Tests/XCDYouTubeKitTestCase.m)
The code is self explanatory.

```
+ (NSArray *)testInvocations
{
    BOOL onlineTests = [[[[NSProcessInfo processInfo] environment] objectForKey:@"ONLINE_TESTS"] boolValue];
    if (!onlineTests)
        return [super testInvocations];

    NSMutableArray *testInvocations = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSInvocation *invocation in [super testInvocations])
    {
        if (![NSStringFromSelector(invocation.selector) hasSuffix:offlineSuffix])
            [testInvocations addObject:invocation];
    }
    return [testInvocations copy];
}
```

If you want to decide which test to run during runtime => you have a code smell in your tests (dependency), which means you are doing tests wrong.

Comment: dependency? e.g. the application uses smart card reader. there can be two readers connected. the tests test using two readers should be run only when the system finds two readers connected. I don't want two fails the whole auto tests because of this.

Comment: If you do this as integration test then it's completely OK. If you do standard tests with real card readers then your tests are wrong and slow (card reader is the dependency).